# DragonMobile Nuance SDK Speech Recognition on iOS.... AURemoteIO::ChangeHardwareFormats: error -10875

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, speech-recognition, audio-recording

I've spent the last few hours trying to figure this out...  I cannot get around this error, which happens on my iPhone 4S inside my project I implemented 1.4.0 of the SDK in, whenever I try to recognize speech:

`AURemoteIO::ChangeHardwareFormats: error -10875`

It works fine in the Simulator.

Also, what's weirder, is that the sample app for voice recognition works on my iPhone 4S.  The code is nearly identical...

The only thing I can think that is different between the two is I have a linker flag -ObjC for TouchDB...  and I'm using ARC.  However, I have also tried disabling ARC for the particular class I use the SDK in.

Comment: I am also happening like you said. It's work fine on Simulator but that error occur in real device.
However that error can't crash and do nothing my app.
Speech To Text function is still working.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I get the same error when my application goes to the background but it does not seem to cause any problems.